# Is there any ways to add css prefix class with app or online generator?

Tags: css

Is there any ways to add custom css prefix class for thousand of line css codes?

I found some solutions, not fully ok

## method1

We could search and replace in editor, but it is not correct for all the cases like float value css.

## method2

I googled and showed me like wrapping custom css class. like below

```
.myprefix .btn {}
.myprefix .text-muted {}
// this solution is not cool
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want like .myprefix-btn, .myprefix-text-muted, .myprefex-bg ?

if you are using SCSS then you can achieve this by following code:

```
.myprefix{
    &-btn{
        color: red;
    }
    &-text-muted{
        color: green;
    }
}
```

Make sure your html inherit those btn, text with parent myprefix.

Answer (score 1):

Enclose your whole CSS with a class-name of your choice.

Example:

```
.myprefix {
  /*Source files*/
}
```

Now you have an SCSS file.

- Then go to this [link](http://www.cssportal.com/scss-to-css/) and copy paste your code and convert it to CSS file.

You'll notice that all the your CSS classes have be preceded with `myprefix`

Comment: Hi @allan-jebaraj , wrapping with .myprefix for every css bracket is not right solution. I want like .myprefix-btn, .myprefix-text-muted, .myprefex-bg ? You know what I mean.